# GetTempPathA returning incorrect user folder

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I need to access the user specific temp folder on windows, which is supposed to be doable with the

```
GetTempPathA()
```

I have something along the lines of:

```
char buff[512];
GetTempPath(500,buff);
strcat(buff,"specific_folder_in_temp\\file.txt");
FILE f*;
f = fopen(buff,"w");
```

However, instead of returning the expected

```
C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Temp\...
```

I'm getting

```
C:\Users\USER~1.NAM\AppData\Local\Temp...
```

This results in my code failing. Any tips as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What does GetTempPathW return?  And what is the values of your TMP, TEMP, and USERPROFILE environment variables?  (Type `set` at command prompt to see your env)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365307/what-determines-the-return-value-of-path-gettemppath

Comment: GetTempPathW didn't seem to return anything at all. It seems that both TMP and TEMP are set to C:\Users\USER~1.NAM\... instead of the expected. However, USERPROFILE seems to be the correct C:\User\User.Name. Could i use that instead?

Comment: As the environment variables `TMP` or `TEMP` may use short path, you could try [`GetLongPathNameA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlongpathnamea) to convert it to the long path format.

Comment: Sounds a bit odd. Why would your code fail when presented with short file names? It sounds much more like the problem is in your code, code that we can't see. Also, not checking return values for errors is surely a problem. Don't do that.

Comment: It's normal that `GetTempPath()` returns a short path and you shouldn't worry about it. As others said, the problem is in the code that you don't show.

Comment: Well, it works if I convert to long form, so I'm sticking to that.

Comment: @Liam `USER~1.NAM` is simply the short 8.3 form of the `user.name` folder.  They are the same folder!  If your code can't handle short and long forms of a given path, then you have bugs in your code. Whether you open `C:\Users\USER~1.NAM\AppData\Local\Temp\specific_folder_in_temp\file.txt` or `C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Temp\specific_folder_in_temp\file.txt`, you are opening the same file. What exactly is failing for you when you get a short path instead of a long path?

Comment: @Liam One thing I do notice in the code you showed is that you are expecting `GetTempPath()` to return a path with a trailing backslash, but that is NOT guaranteed (despite what the documentation says). Use `PathAddBackslash()` or similar to ensure the slash is present before calling `strcat()` (better, use `PathCchCombineEx()` instead).

Answer (score 4):

`something~1.ext` is a short name. Short names are generated for compatibility with DOS/16-bit applications. Short name generation can be turned off globally or per volume with `fsutil`. Applications should not care if the path is short or long because a user may use either as input in your application.

> **[Why does the system convert TEMP to a short file name?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041224-00/?p=36893/)**
>
> When you set environment variables with the System control panel, the
>   TEMP and TMP variables are silently converted to their short file name
>   equivalents (if possible). Why is that?
>
> For compatibility, of course.
>
> It is very common for batch files to  assume that the paths referred
>   to by the %TEMP% and %TMP% environment variables  do not contain any
>   embedded spaces. (Other programs may also make this assumption, but
>   batch files are the most common place where you run into this
>   problem.)
>
> I say "if possible" because  you can disable short name generation, in
>   which case there is no short name equivalent, and the path remains in
>   its original long form.

You should use a function like [`PathCchAppend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchappend) to join path elements because it takes care of the backslashes for you.