# IIS error: Access to the path 'D:\temp\...\hash.web' is denied -

Tags: asp.net, iis

My ASP.net 3.5 site, hosted on a shared hosting provider, started showing "Access to the path 'D:\temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\385288b9\3cc848e\hash\hash.web' is denied" 
(I have no access to the files on the server, other than my hosted site).

Any idea ????

Answer (score 0):

This path to **temporary asp.net files** can be overriden by yourself in the machine.config or web.config file, in the  element which contains the "tempDirectory" attribute. *You can check the following reference in MSDN about this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx (lost MSDN reference)* and the specific instruction to edit the file is given in [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/350550/is-it-possible-to-configure-the-location-of-temporary-asp-net-files-folder-in).

Also, some debugging is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542312/asp-net-access-to-the-temp-directory-is-denied)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It seems that I will need to contact my hosting support after all, since I have not enough privileges for changing these values on web.config.

Comment: Unfortunately that MSDN article has been removed.

Comment: @spuder check the new link to SF :)