# Where does the Xml Serializer store its dynamically generated code?

Tags: xml-serialization, xmlserializer, codedom, system-codedom-compiler

The XML serializer in `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace generates the `XmlSerializationReader` and `XmlSerializationWriter` classes dynamically using *CodeDOM*.

I want to have a look at these classes in the disassembler.

Where does the serializer store the temporary assembly file that has this dynamically generated code? I have been trying to find it out for the last 30 minutes in Reflector but to no avail.

All I gather from Reflector is that it stores it in some temp directory. I looked up **C:\temp** but there's no .dll there. I looked up **C:\tmp** and there are some PNG files there that seem like they are not really PNG's but some binary files generated by Windows for storing temporary data.

If you know, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, these two threads out of the dozen or so pertaining to this issue that I looked up reveal the answer.

This thread says it is the folder **C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp**

http://snavin.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/xmlserializer-is-running-does-not-have-sufficient-permission-to-access-the-temp-directory/

But from the stack trace posted in the original question on this thread, it appears that the temp folder of the windows environment, which can be found out by calling `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` is where the dll is saved.

[ASP.NET Access to the temp directory is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542312/asp-net-access-to-the-temp-directory-is-denied)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way: use `sgen.exe` to generate necessary assembly by yourself.

On my machine it looks like:

```
C:>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\sgen.exe" "C:\Projects\BIN\My.dll"
Microsoft (R) Xml Serialization support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.6.1055.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Serialization Assembly Name: My.XmlSerializers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
Generated serialization assembly for assembly c:\projects\bin\My.dll --> 'c:\projects\bin\My.XmlSerializers.dll'.
```

Comment: Did you mean `sgen`? `ngen` is for the native images.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Fixed.